ABAP select with primary key in HANA applying condition to whole primary key
Is there a way to implement a full primary key select? I will explain it in more detail in the following lines.
I have to process all records of a table in sequence, using cursors, if the process ends by error (dump, system crash, system boot...) we want to restart the process right at the point where we left off, so that when a cursor block ends, we will mark it in the system persistently. The next execution of the process will look for a previous unfinished execution to start the selection from that point. My problem is that said table has a multi-column primary key.
The selection is always in primary key order, is there a way to express a where condition where I can specify to start right after said primary key? Without having to manually discard all previous records.
If I have a table with columns A and B as primary key with the following data:



A
B




1
1


1
2


1
3


1
4


2
1


2
2


3
3


5
4



I run the process and I finished processing row 5 (2,1), the process ends before completing the whole set and I want to run it again. If I do it with a classic where, I would have to put:
A > 2 or ( A = 2 and B > 1 ).
With 2 columns it is easy, but if the number of columns is high, we would have to write a complex expression. In addition, we process the table dynamically, since we have to process N tables, so the process has to dynamically build the where condition. Also, this type of conditions will surely have an impact on performance.
Thanks in advance

Am I getting this correctly?
Lets say 1/4 (A/B values) fails you want

find 1/3 (last success)
Based on 1/3 find next record (assumed to have failed) 1/4 and start from there.

What you said with A > 2 or ( A = 2 and B > 1 ) is the only efficient way to do it by primary key that doesn't involve secondary tables. If it's not a viable way (either too many fields or other constraints), you should be looking at at other ways to query that data such as select ... where A > '1' completed = ' ' (use as many fields on the left as you can specify completely and filter the rest by status).
In the long term, I would suggesting implementing some sort of batch management, where you decide on what goes into a batch before processing it (instead of going record by record). In process of designing batches you will end up figuring out an efficient way to group data (maybe process all records with the same A at once, or A and first symbol of B, or maybe even just A but divide portions by fixed number of records). There's not much I can help with on this end since that would require in depth analysis.
Anyways, with an extra table to record batches and their status your solution will likely end up easier to understand and troubleshoot later down the line.
